# How to use display() on more than one array

Tags: php, twig

I am trying to pass more than one array to the Twig display() method.
My code contains several functions returning arrays. 
I do have one parent template (parent.phtml) and several child templates (child_n.phtml) which are extending the parent template.

This is the relevant part of index.php:

```
$template = $twig->loadTemplate('child_1.phtml');
$template->display(function_1());
```

Declaration of the Twig environment etc. is happening in another file which is included.

With the code above everything works fine.
But what I want to do, is displaying more than one array. So I have tried

```
$template->display(function_1(), function_2());
```

This does not work. When using `$template->display();` twice, the parent template is being displayed twice...

So what might be a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several ways to solve your problem :

1) If your `function_1()` and `function_2()` do return arrays with distinct keys, you can use [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) to merge all arrays.

```
$template->display(array_merge(function_1(), function_2()));
```

So if `function_1()` returns `array("a" => 42)` and `function_2()` returns `array("b" => 84)`, you can use `{{ a }}` and `{{ b }}` in your twig file to access your values.

2) If your `function_1()` and `function_2()` do return arrays with some similar keys, you need to give a name to them :

```
$twigVars = array();
$twigVars['array1'] = function_1();
$twigVars['array2'] = function_2();
$template->display($twigVars);
```

So if `function_1()` returns `array("a" => 42)` and `function_2()` returns `array("a" => 84)`, you can use `{{ array1.a }}` to access 42 and `{{ array2.a }}` to access 84 in your twig file.

Comment: I am using array_merge for now. Thanks!